# How to optimize jquery grep method on 30k records array

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Is it possible to optimize this code? I have very low performance on this keyup event.

```
$('#opis').keyup(function () {

  if ($('#opis').val() != "") {
    var search = $.grep(
    svgs, function (value) {
      reg = new RegExp('^' + $('#opis').val(), 'i');
      return value.match(reg) == null;
    }, true);
    $('#file_list').html("");
    var tohtml = "";

    $cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
      if ($cnt <= 30) {
        tohtml += "<li class='file_item'><a href='' class='preview'>" + search[i] + "</a> <a href='" + search[i] + "' class='print_file'><img src='img/add16px.png' alt='dodaj'/></li></a>";
        $cnt++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    $('#file_list').html(tohtml);
    $(".preview").click(function () {
      $('#file_preview').html('<embed src="opisy/' + $(this).html() + '" type="image/svg+xml" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" /> ');
      $(".preview").parent().removeClass("selected");
      $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
      return false;
    });

    $(".print_file").click(function () {
      if (jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('href'), prints) == -1) {
        $('#print_list').append('<li>' + $(this).attr('href') + '</li>');
        prints.push($(this).attr('href'));
      } else {
        alert("Plik znajduje się już na liście do wydruku!");
      }
      return false;
    });
  } else {
    $('#file_list').html("  &nbsp;");
  }
});
```

Comment: For starters, keep some variable references around instead of re-querying for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var opis = $('#opis')[0]; // this line can go outside of keyup  
var search = [];
var re = new RegExp('^' + opis.value, 'i');
for (var i = 0, len = svgs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (re.test(svgs[i])) {
        search.push(svgs[i]);
    }
}
```

It's up to [**100x faster**](http://jsperf.com/grep) in Google Chrome, **60x** in IE 6.

Comment: Thanks. It's little bit faster, however I made this server side already and it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing with javascript is that it executes under the users environment and not the servers environment so optimization always varies, with large large arrays that need extensive work done on them to I would prefer to handle this server side.

Have you thought about serializing the data and passing them over to your server side, which would handle all the data calculations / modifications and return the prepared result back as the response.

You may also want to take alook at [SE:Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for more optimization advise.

Some optimization, tips:

- `if($('#opis').val()!=""){` should be using `'!=='`.
- `return value.match(reg)==null;` should be `===`.
- `for(var i=0;i<search.length;i++){`
- `reg = new RegExp(...);` should be `var reg ...` as its not defined outside the function as a global.
- Move all your variable declarations to the top of the function such as

  - `var i,cnt,search,tohtml` etc

i would advise you to start using Google Chrome, it has a built in system for memeory tracking on perticular tabs, you can go to the url [about:memory](http://about:memory) in chrome, which would produce a result like so:

[image: Google Memory Resources]

Image taken from: http://malektips.com/google-chrome-memory-usage.html

Comment: Somewhere I've read that JS can easily handle up to 1 million array. Server side method was my first thought, but if there is no other way I will use PHP. Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Also, take a look at my edit, a small tip to help you optimize.

Answer (score 1):

first thing you have to learn:

```
$('#opis').keyup(function() {
    $this = $(this);
            if($this.val()!=""){

// so *$this* instead of *$('#opis')*
// because you are reperforming a *getElementById("opis")* and you've already called it when you used the keyup method.
// and use $this instead of $(this) | pretty much the same problem
```

so about the grep function, maybe if you cache the results it would help in further searchs I guess, but I don't know if can help you with that

Answer (score 1):

Each time you perform the `grep`, you are calling the 'matching' function once per array entry.

The matching function creates a `RegExp` object and then uses it to perform the match.

There are two ways you could improve this:

1. Create the `RegExp` once, outside of the function, and then use a closure to capture it inside the function, so that you don't have to keep recreating the object over and over.
2. It looks like all you're trying to do is to perform a case-insensitive tests to see whether the sought string is the start of a member of your array. It *may* be faster to do this more explicitly, using `.toUpper` and `substring`. However, that's a guess and you should test to find out.